# blank page between appendix and references

Tags: header-footer, blank-page

firstly I am getting a blank page between my references and appendix, I have tried all the usual fixes like `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage`, but having no luck. Secondly the header will not show on my appendix, as can be seen by the code the header even given but does not carry down, the header line is their across the top of the page but no text.

```
%Document style
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

%Packages used to format document
\usepackage[a4paper,top=40mm, bottom=40mm, left=40mm, right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{vector} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

%Preambles goes here

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancyplain}  
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}                    
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 

\chapter{Discussion/Comparison}

\chapter{Conclusion}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\renewcommand\bibname{References/Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References/Bibliography}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.6em}}  

\section*{References}

\section*{Bibliography}

\end{thebibliography}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{appendices}

\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}

\section*{\\Appendix A - Design Work Sheets} \label{App:AppendixA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A - Design Work Sheets}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.6em}} 

\vspace*{\fill}

\includepdf[pages={1}]{Aggregate-work-sheet-results.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={1}]{cube-design-sheet.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={1}]{cylinder-design-sheet.pdf}

\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}

\section*{\\Appendix B - Strength Relationship} \label{App:AppendixB}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix B - Strength Relationship}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.6em}} 


The following graphs represent the cylinder/cube strength relationship ratio for all curing methods separately.

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{ratio1.jpg}
\caption{Cylinder/Cube strength relationship ratio for sample cured at -22$\degree$C}
\label{fig:fig8.1}
\end{figure}

\vspace*{\fill}

\end{appendices}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301232/blank-page-between-references-and-appendix????

Comment: This document is a total mess, sorry. It's not compilable, and totally unclear

Comment: Sorry Christian Hupfer, but how can i make it clearer?

Comment: Please add some explanations about the real requirements. Shall the appendix sections be numbered? Unnumbered sections do not use `\sectionmark{}`, which produces the heading line on the page header. The empty page after the `References` is difficult to track`. Is it really empty?

Comment: The appendix sections are unnumbered, what i am trying to do is have APPENDIX A as the header at the top right and APPENDIX B for the second section

Comment: If you would use `\chapter` as Appendix and not section (you are using the book class!) the whole stuff would be much easier. Instead, the strange style etc. screws the whole setting up. I leave this question to others

Comment: @ChristianHupfer would it be possible to email my report to you, its a thesis I am doing for college and would appreciate your help

Comment: I fear your thesis is in very strange state concerning the LaTeX code -- too much to be changed, most likely